# Broadcasting to multiple turbo streams with hotwire

Tags: turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-6.1, hotwire-rails

I've got hotwire/turbo wired up correctly to do crud operations on a single model on one place of my page, but I'd like to update the same model at the same time in a different location on my page as well. I thought I could just set up two streams but it doesn't seem to work.

Specifying a target does work for create action depending on how I name the target, but not for update and destroy. This is what I think should work but doesn't:

----location 1 ("creatures" stream)----

```
<div id="creatures">
  <%= turbo_stream_from "creatures" %>
  <%= turbo_frame_tag "creatures" do %>
    <div>
      <% @creatures.each do |creature| %>
        <div>
          <%= render "creatures/creature", creature: creature %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

----location 2 ("creatures_main" stream)----

```
<%= turbo_stream_from "creatures_main" %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "creatures_main" do %>
  <% @creatures.each do |creature| %>
    <div>
      <%= render "creatures/creature", creature: creature %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---- common _creature.html.erb partial ----

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(creature) do %>
  <%= link_to creature.name, "#" %>
<% end %>
```

---- creature.rb ----

```
class Creature < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true

  after_create_commit {
    broadcast_append_to "creatures"
    broadcast_append_to "creatures_main"
    }
  after_update_commit {
    broadcast_replace_to "creatures"
    broadcast_replace_to "creatures_main"
    }
  after_destroy_commit {
    broadcast_remove_to "creatures"
    broadcast_remove_to "creatures_main"
    }

end
```

What happen when I have two calls in my model is that the create action puts the newly created creature in location 1 twice, only 1 of the two are updated,but both are destroyed correctly regardless of where on the page they are.

Answer (score 4):

`creatures` and `creatures_main` would be the stream name. What you're looking for is the `target` and `partial` to control where the stream would look to update your data, and which partial it would use to update.

You can try:

```
after_create_commit -> {
  # target here is the ID of the outer div, where data would be appended to
  broadcast_append_to "creatures", target: "creatures"`
  broadcast_append_to "creatures_main", target: "creatures_main"
}
after_update_commit {
  # target here is the ID of each of the creature div
  broadcast_replace_to "creatures", target: "creature_#{id}"
  broadcast_replace_to "creatures_main", target: "creature_main_#{id}"
}
after_destroy_commit {
  broadcast_remove_to "creatures"
  broadcast_remove_to "creatures_main"
}
```

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "creature_#{creature.id}" do %>
  <%= link_to creature.name, "#" %>
<% end %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag "creature_main_#{creature.id}" do %>
  <%= link_to creature.name, "#" %>
<% end %>
```

Of course this means you might have to use 2 different partials if you have the `turbo_frame_tag` inside the partial. You can do so like this:

```ruby
after_update_commit {
  # target here is the ID of each of the creature div
  broadcast_replace_to "creatures", target: "creature_#{id}", partial: "creatures/creature", locals: {creature: self}
  broadcast_replace_to "creatures_main", target: "creature_main_#{id}", partial: "creatures/creature_main", locals: {creature: self}
}
```

Btw, you should use the _later version of those methods. Also use render collection for easier reading.